# My JavaScript is only working in Safari and Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html-table, dreamweaver

I was writing a JavaScript code for an exercise using Adobe Dreamweaver.

The code works within the Dreamweaver "live" display, as well as Safari, but in all other browsers I tested (Chrome, Firefox, IE) it didn't work:

**JavaScript**

```
function car1(){
  var table = document.getElementById("carstable");
  table.rows(1).cells(0).innerHTML="20";
  table.rows(1).cells(1).innerHTML="19";
}

function car2(){
  var table = document.getElementById("carstable");
  table.rows(1).cells(0).innerHTML="25";
  table.rows(1).cells(1).innerHTML="24";
}

function calculate(){
  var table = document.getElementById("carstable"); 
  var days = document.getElementById("nbOfCars");
  days = days.value;
  days = parseInt(days);


  var total = document.getElementById("total");

  var TOTAL = 0;

  if(days > 2 && days < 8){
    TOTAL += table.rows(1).cells(0).innerHTML * days;
  } else {
    TOTAL += table.rows(1).cells(1).innerHTML * days;
  }

  total.value = TOTAL + "$";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

How many days &nbsp <input type="text" id="nbOfCars" /> 
</br>
car 1 &nbsp <input type="radio" name="car" value="1" onchange="car1()" />
car 2 &nbsp <input type="radio" name="car"  value="2" onchange="car2()" />
</br>
Total payment <input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly" />

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()" />
</br>

<table border="1" id="carstable" >
    <tr> <th> 2-7</th><th>8+</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Now, what could the problem be?

Comment: You should always use html5 doctype. If you tell us what the problem is, we can fix it. Will the page display?

Comment: Yes, the page is displayed but the JavaScript code is not working. by choosing car1 or car2, a new row should be inserted to the table.

Comment: check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oytoqu7s/)

Comment: Yeah, it is working now by changing () to []. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript (in my chrome console at least) `.rows(1)` will not work.

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

You need to use square brackets to get your row and cell,

```
table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML = "20";
```

Comment: Thanks! this one works. I changed all the () to []. Safari can understand both of them.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes, it does. Or dreamweaver. I'm wondering if it's a bug, or a "feature" - you haven't found anything more on it have you?